# Do septuple (7), octuple (8) or nonuple (9) star system exist?

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics, stars, observational-astronomy, stellar-physics

The highest I found so far is Castor, a sextuple star system. And there doesn't seem to be any other sextuple star system within at least 100 light-years...

Comment: Are you asking if they theoretically can exist or if they have been observed.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the systems I found:
6:
[ADS 9731](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADS_9731)
[Beta Tucanae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_Tucanae)
[Gamma Velorum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_Velorum)
[Kappa Tauri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kappa_Tauri)
[Mu Sagittarii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_Sagittarii)

7:
[AR Cassiopeiae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AR_Cassiopeiae)
[Nu Scorpii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nu_Scorpii)

... no physical multiple stars of greater multiplicity yet found.

Comment: Note, though, that both [AR Cassiopeiae](http://www.astrostudio.org/xhip.php?hip=115990) and [Nu Scorpii](http://www.astrostudio.org/xhip.php?hip=79374) are over the 100 light-year limit OP requested.

Comment: @KyleKanos I believe that they all are, I didn't realize there was a limit. I had assume that the OP had referenced a list that only extended out to 100 ly, so he may not care how far the stars actually are.

Comment: From an astrophysics point of view, I don't care about distances either, the dynamics of an $n$-tuple system is amazingly beautiful to even consider. From an astronomy point of view, resolving such a system might be nice & having close examples to study the system would allow that. So it really depends on your interests whether such an (arbitrary) limit matters.

Comment: That said, OP states *within at least 100 light-years...* which indicates he *is* interested in the distance of the stars.

Comment: And of course one could believe in 8 stars - it would be the same three hierarchical separations as in 5-, 6-, and 7-star systems. But 9 stars would require 4 separate scales, which is rather more difficult to believe would ever happen.

Answer (score 0):

Sextenary:
Castor
Beta Tucanae
88 Tauri
65 Ursae Majoris
HD 139691
Beta Scorpii
HD 79506
WDS J19406+1355

Septenary:
Nu Scorpii

Octonary:
Gamma Cassiopeiae (unconfirmed)

Nonary:
None